# How to fix kernel error in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0: "Failed to start the kernel"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, arcgis

I'm getting the following an error when trying to run a python script in ArcGIS Pro (3.1.0) that it has "failed to start the kernel":

```
AttributeError: 'IOLoopKernelManager' object has no attribute 'kernel_cmd'
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled ArcGIS Pro, Python, Anaconda, VS code, etc. multiple times. After uninstalling and reinstalling ArcGIS Pro, the error disappears and it works fine for about a day, but then the same error comes back.

I've also tried cloning the python environment. The same error is still there.

This happens for all projects in ArcGIS Pro and in both the default and cloned environments.

I can't keep uninstalling and reinstalling ArcGIS Pro every time I need to use it. Any suggestions, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, I uninstalled ArcGIS and then deleted these files

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS
```

```
C:\Users\nicks\AppData\Local\ESRI
```

And then reinstalled ArcGIS 3.0, updating to 3.1.3 seems to have screwed it up, so I'd stick with 3.0.

I suspect the culprit is in one of these files and/or 3.1.3.

Update: After closing and reopening ArcGIS, the kernel died again. I'll just copy and paste stuff from the notebook in the python window.

Answer (score 0):

I perceived that performing an ArcGIS Pro clean uninstall and deleting the Python folder in "C:\Users<your_user>\AppData\Roaming" fix the issue.

However, it might not be the best solution if you have another software using Python installed there, but if it is expendable, as in my case, it will fix it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35606807)